# Search for file of a specific pattern in a directory

Tags: java, file, recursion

In **Java**, how do I check folders recursively for a file of a specific pattern? I've seen the below code in a lot of posts online:

```
public static void findFiles() throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(".");
    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(files[i]);
    }
}
```

In my application, I basically need to check files matching `*.txt` in a user's home directory.

Since the path will vary for each user, how do I use this code to search for a file matching a pattern anywhere on the *filesystem*?

Comment: well for a start this method is only checking the current directory `new File(".");`  if you changed this to a recursive method, you could path is each sub-directory as the start directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually simply use:

```
final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

This would set the `dir` to your user's `home` directory. From there, you simply have to list all the `.txt` files, not recursively ;)

---

However, if you still want to list all files from a directory, recursively, you can use the following method:

```
public static List<File> walk(final File root, final String extension) {
    final File[] list = root.listFiles();
    if (list == null) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    final List<File> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            res.addAll(walk(f, extension));
        } else {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
                res.add(f);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (final File file : walk(new File("/home/user3751169"), ".txt")) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to look only for the files in the `home` directory of the current user, you should remove the recursive call to `walk()`:

```
public static List<File> walk(final File root, final String extension) {
    final File[] list = root.listFiles();
    if (list == null) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    final List<File> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final File f : list) {
        if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
            res.add(f);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set a propert for the home directory of the user. What other option do I have?

Comment: Actually, this property is already set by the JVM. However, here's an alternative solution :)

Comment: Okay, if I invoke this method from main, what parameter do I pass for the file argument?

Comment: When I invoke walk in main method, how do I not specify a hardcoded path :( If I try the user home dir as you mentioned - walk(new File(System.getProperty("user.home",".txt"))), it hangs. Its very slow.

Comment: Of course it does. Walking through the whole user's directory recursively is terribly long. However, if you want to look only for the files in the home directory of the user, you should remove the recursive call to `walk`. Let me show you.

Comment: No it won't necessarily be in the user's home directory. It could be anywhere.

Comment: Just call it with the *root* path of your file system then (e.g.: `"/"` or `"C:"`). But this is gonna take a long time, because there are a **lot** of files on your computer, there's nothing you can do about that :)

Comment: @user3751169 Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you got your response, so the quality of this website remains great :)